# XHR Download public google drive file of a different user with OR without gdrive api

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, google-drive-api

So using the google drive api I'm uploading a file.

I would like for a DIFFERENT user to be able to download that file using cross domain XHR, either with or without the google drive API.

The key point here is that the file is NOT in the drive of the user downloading the file.

Can this be done?

In an ideal world, I wouldn't have to request drive.file scope when authorizing the downloading user.

Answer (score -2):

The user can download any file they have read access to, even if they are not the original creator.  Just share the file with the user that you want to have download it.